# new iTunes connect build status in prerelease view

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

Now my App is in 'waiting for review' status on iTunes connect.

However, when I check in 'prerelease' view, it says that my uploaded file is an 'invalid binary'. But if I check in the detail view, the 'binary state' is shown 'validated.'

Any suggestion about this issue will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Please check your email associated with your apple developer account. Apple will send email to your mailbox with some diagnose information and how to solve your problem.

Comment: look at the following answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25816828/app-submission-binary-does-not-show-up-in-itunesconnect/25816865#25816865

Comment: and check out http://stackoverflow.com/a/26144339/294884

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25816828/app-submission-binary-does-not-show-up-in-itunesconnect/25816865#25816865

Answer (score 0):

It take in my experience about 1 day ( to be exact about 36 hours from UK ).

It can be challenging when trying to send demos to customers who want to see the app.

Internal testers are immediate.